# getting and setting application preferences with the App SDK

Tags: rally

How do you store and retrieve application preferences using the App SDK?

I see in some of the scripts they seem to use use:

```
rallyDataSource.preferences.getAppPreferences()
rallyDataSource.preferences.update()
rally.sdk.data.Preferences.parse()
```

Are these documented anywhere?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those functions are for unsupported and undocumented in the AppSDK. We never were able to make the preference functionality simple enough for us to fully include in the AppSdk.

I would recommend saving the Preferences manually.

Here are some things to remember when dealing with preferences.

Preferences require a name and a scoping parameter.
The combination of the scoping and the name must be unique. This code will show you how to save a preference that is name spaced to your current workspace and namespace it by the apps current id. It will not work external to a Rally App tab unless you replace **WORKSPACE_OID** with a workspace's object id.

```
        var value = { value : true };
        rallyDataSource.create("preference",
                {
                    Name: prefNameKey + rally.sdk.util.Context.getAppInfo().getAppId(),
                    Workspace: "/workspace/__WORKSPACE_OID__",
                    Value: dojo.toJson(value)
                }, function() {
                }, function() {
                });
```

Comment: I take it a "preference" is just like any other rally object, and so I can get it back by doing a rallyDataSource.get(reference)?

Comment: Yeah, it is the same. In the above case I would probably query by Name and Workspace though.

Comment: Ok got this working no problem.  A few questions:

I assume if I want prefs personalized to a user, I just incorporate their userID in the Name of the preference?
* In general, what is the convention for the structure of the "Name" field?
* What is the size limitation of the Value field?

Comment: So you can create a preference that is scoped to a specific user in the same way that we scope them to workspace above. That may be easier, it depends on what you are making.